# How to show multiple already plotted matplotlib figures side-by-side or on-top in Python without re-plotting them?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, subplot

I have already plotted two figures separately in a single **jupyter notebook** file, and exported them.

What I want is to *show* them side by side, but *not* plot them again by using `matplotlib.pyplot.subplots`.

For example, in *Mathematica*, it's easier to do this by just saving the figures into a Variable, and displaying them afterwards.

What I tried was saving the figures, using

```
fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots(1,1)
... #plotting using ax1.plot()
fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots(1,1)
... #plotting using ax2.plot()
```

Now, those `fig1` or `fig2` are of type `Matplotlib.figure.figure` which stores the figure as an 'image-type' instance. I can even see them separately by calling just `fig1` or `fig2` in my notebook.

But, I can not show them together as by doing something like

```
plt.show(fig1, fig2)
```

It returns nothing since, there wasn't any figures currently being plotted.

You may look at [this link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32920/70451) or [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zpyiz.jpg), which is a Mathematica version of what I was talking about.

Comment: Your title should have been specific to your actual need because you answer it for the singular instance, which your title addresses, in your post. By the end of your post you aren't asking what someone ending up here because of that title would be looking for. You are asking something different there. (Along that vein that your text has the answer to your current title, I think `ax1.figure` or `ax2.figure` work as well to bring up each individual plot in a later cell after the original plotting).

Answer (score 1):

assuming u want to merge those subplots in the end.
Here is the code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#e.x function to plot
x = np.linspace(0, 10)
y = np.exp(x)

#almost your code
figure, axes = plt.subplots(1,1)
res_1, = axes.plot(x,y) #saving the results in a tuple
plt.show()
plt.close(figure)
figure, axes = plt.subplots(1,1)
res_2, = axes.plot(x,-y) #same before
plt.show()


#restructure to merge
figure_2, (axe_1,axe_2) = plt.subplots(1,2)  #defining rows and columns
axe_1.plot(res_1.get_data()[0], res_1.get_data()[1]) #using the already generated data 
axe_2.plot(res_2.get_data()[0], res_2.get_data()[1])
#if you want show them in one

plt.show()
```

Comment: I can see that it's doing the job nicely, but by re-plotting the plotted data from the `axes` (`matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot` object). That's great, but my main point was about optimization, that once the figure is plotted, isn't there a way to just show the `matplotlib.figure.Figure` object side by side? Note that, this is a `figure` object without any reference to the data (unlike `axes` which had reference to the data which you extracted and re-plotted)

Comment: i don't think it's possible if you define at the start with (1,1) subplot.  secondly the main complexity comes from calculation of arrays not plotting.  plotting itself doesn't matter actually.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you mean with:

> but not plot them again by using `matplotlib.pyplot.subplots`.

But you can display two figures next to each other in a jupyter notebook by using:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2)

ax[0] = ...  # Code for first figure
ax[1] = ...  # Code for second figure

plt.show()
```

Or above each other:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1)

ax[0] = ...  # Top figure
ax[1] = ...  # Bottom figure

plt.show()
```